# Having issue in migrating GCM to FCM

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

Currently, I am migrating my project from Gcm to Fcm. But when i use Fcm library gradle dependencies i got this error.

**Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.0.0**

Can Anyone help me to resolve this error.

Comment: add that library in your project

Answer (score 1):

Versions of all libraries have to be equal to each other. I am using 9.0.2

Answer (score 0):

if you already mentioned , please try to write

```
dependencies {
     compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.0"
}
```

instead of

```
dependencies {
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0"
}
```